# SQL Using max value from a table as the starting number in an Identity column

Tags: identity

This is a stupid question, but here it goes.  I need to use the result of the first query as the
starting number in an Identity column.  I don't want to do it manually each time.

```
 SELECT MAX([VM_KEY]) + 1   as  VM_KEY FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]  --30474373

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [Segment_Name] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [Segment_Name_Flag] [varchar](38) NULL, 
    [Counter] [int] NULL,
    [VM_KEY] [int] IDENTITY(30474373,1) NOT NULL)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will you get an error if you move the select statement as a first parameter in the identity? New to SQL as well

Comment: It will work this way:     select top 100
 [Segment_Name],  
 [Segment_Name_Flag], 
 [Counter],  
 IDENTITY(int, 30474373,1) AS [VM_KEY] 
 into dbo.test
 FROM [dbo].[WM_VNDR_Default_Columns_counter_final]     I just don't want to do it manually.